# Setting Flash drive as a variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, command-line

I have a long script that gets lots of different info for laptops that we are donating to United Way and because of the commands I have to run as Admin.
But when I do `set drive=%cd:~0,3%` Sets to C:\Windows\System32 instead of the Flash Drive I am running it from.

Does anyone know how to get the correct info needed?

I have looked on here and Google and nothing really matches the issue.

`set drive=%cd:~0,3%`
Here is some more of the code so you can see what I am trying to do.

```
set drive=%cd:~0,3%
```

`for /F "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=," %%A in ('wmic systemenclosure get serialnumber /FORMAT:csv') do (set "serial=%%A") mkdir %cd%\Computers\%Serial%\`

Comment: Prior to using `set drive=%cd:~0,3%`, have you included `CD /D "%~dp0"` to ensure the batch is actually executing from the flash drive? Note the `/D` switch - it is required when changing from one drive to another.

Comment: Of course you could just use `%~d0` which is already a variable holding the drive letter of the running batch file. If you wanted to save it as a variable named `drive` use `Set "drive=%~d0"`.

Comment: I tried both of those and when I right click and run as admin it still echos C:\Windows\System32.......

Comment: The advice you've been given does not echo a full path to the `\System32` directory, because at no point do either of those two comments use `%cd%`. Please therefore post exactly what is contained in your problem batch file, making sure that `echo` is not `off`, run it from a Command Prompt window, opened using the 'Run as administrator' option, and also post the complete output.

Comment: If I right click the Batch File and select Run As Administrator, it changes to \system32. I am guessing because I am evoking the admin and its opening that way........

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.
This worked for me.

Open up registry editor and go here:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

Change EnableLUA to 0

Restart computer.

Thank you for the help everyone

Comment: This does not answer or resolve your issue. All EnableLUA does is notify a User if a program tries to modify their settings, it is essentially the UAC notification. Windows prompts for consent or credentials of a valid local administrator account before starting a program or task that requires a full administrator access token. However, as you've already invoked this script using Run as administrator, all that this does is control a notification when you invoke that script. It does not affect any of the execution of code in that script, especially the values of the `%0` or `%CD%` variables.